# Why does the coordinate transformation from Cartesian coordinates leads to an additional term in the biharmonic operator in spherical coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

I am trying to solve a problem in physics where the biharmonic operator is involved. I think that the bihahmonic operator can be obtained by taking twice the Laplace operator, such that $\nabla^4 f = \nabla^2 (\nabla^2 f)$. 
Here $f$ is a function of the polar angle $\phi$ only (i.e. in the axisymmetric case for the sake of simplicity.)
In this way, the Laplace operator reads
$$
\nabla^2 f(\phi) = \frac{1}{a^2 \sin\phi} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \left( \sin\phi \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} \right) \, ,
$$
where $a$ being the sphere radius.
In principle, the biharmonic operator is obtained after applying twice the above operation, to obtain
$$
\nabla^4 f(\phi) = \frac{1}{a^4} 
\left( 
\frac{\partial^4 f}{\partial \phi^4} 
+ 2\cot\phi \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial \phi^3}
-(2+\cot^2 \phi) \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \phi^2}
+\cot\phi (1+\cot^2\phi) \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}
\right) \, .
$$
However, if we start from the biharmonic equation in Cartesian coordinates, namely
$$
\nabla^4 f(x,y,z) = \frac{\partial^4 f}{\partial x^4} 
+ \frac{\partial^4 f}{\partial y^4} 
+ \frac{\partial^4 f}{\partial z^4}
+ 2 \left( 
\frac{\partial^4 f}{\partial x^2 \partial y^2}
+ \frac{\partial^4 f}{\partial y^2 \partial z^2}
+ \frac{\partial^4 f}{\partial x^2 \partial z^2}
\right) \, ,
$$
and apply the coordinate transformation to spherical, e.g. using Maple `PDEchangecoords` and of course drop the dependence on $r$ and $\theta$, I get the following biharmonic
$$
\nabla^4 f(\phi) = \frac{1}{a^4} 
\left( 
\frac{\partial^4 f}{\partial \phi^4} 
+ 2\cot\phi \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial \phi^3}
-\cot^2 \phi\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \phi^2}
+\cot\phi (3+\cot^2\phi) \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}
\right) \, ,
$$
i.e. the following additional terms appear
$$
\frac{2}{a^4} \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \phi^2} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} \cot \phi \right) \, , 
$$

My question is which resulting biharmonic operator is correct? What is the reason behind the discrepancy between the two results.
Thank you,

a

Comment: Could you exactly say which results are not the same? You have the the Laplace operator in spherical coordinates, the biharmonic equation in Cartesian coordinates and you have a piece of the biharmonic eqaution in spherical coordinates. Are you comparing biharmonic Cartesian vs the biharmonic in spherical. Maybe this source will help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-qsKu00tVY

Comment: thanks @MrYouMath for your comment / link. The first approach would be to apply the Laplacian in spherical coordinates twice and you will get a result, say [Res. 1]. If you transform the biharmonic equation from Cartesian to spherical using Maple you get a result, say [Res. 2]. You will immediately notice that [Res. 1] and [Res. 2] are not the same. In fact the difference [Res. 2] - [Ref. 1] gives you the additional term written above. I was wondering why is it that the two results are not the same? Thanks.

Comment: @MrYouMath Post just updated with further details. I would appreciate your feedback on that. Very much thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are conflating the Biharmonic operator $\Delta^2$ of the sphere (the first one in your question) with the one $\bar \Delta^2$ of  $\mathbb R^3;$ i.e. you are assuming that when $f : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ depends only on $\phi, \theta$ that $\Delta^2 f = \bar \Delta^2 f$. The equivalent statement for the Laplacian is true since $\bar \Delta f = \Delta f + \partial_r ^2 f$; but for $\Delta^2$ it simply isn't. The correct expression is

$$ \bar \Delta^2 f = \bar \Delta (\Delta f + \partial_r ^2 f) = \bar \Delta \Delta f = \Delta^2 f + \partial_r^2 \Delta f.$$

The terms $\Delta \partial_r^2 f$ and $\partial_r^4 f$ disappear because $f$ does not depend on $r$, *but the $\partial_r^2 \Delta f$ does not*. This is what John's answer and comments are getting at - since the coordinate expression for $\Delta f$ depends on the sphere radius, $\bar \Delta^2$ and $\Delta^2$ do not agree even in the symmetric case.

Answer (score 4):

Since you did not show your work, I can only conjecture that you forgot to differentiate $a$ in

$$\Delta f = \frac{1}{a^2 \sin\phi} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \left( \sin\phi \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} \right) + \frac{1}{a^2\sin^2\phi} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \theta^2} \, ,
$$

In the next step, if you want to take $\Delta$ again, note then $\Delta f$ is NOT independent of $a$. So you have to use the general formula, which has an extra term:

$$\frac{1}{a^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left( a^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right)$$

Since

$$\left[\frac{1}{a^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left( a^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right)\right] \frac{1}{a^2} = \frac{2}{a^4},$$

so if you really missed that, you will be off with the term as stated.

Comment: Very much thanks John for your reply. I have just updated the post so that people can understand it better. In fact, I am considering here a tangential case in which the dependence on the sphere radius a is dropped out. Moreover, I have considered the axisymmetric case to illustrate the idea. I would be happy if you could please have a look again at it and come out with your feedback. Thank you.

Comment: John: Please note that I consider here a tangential biharmonic in the axisymmetric case. I.e. the function f is only function of the polar angle phi. Thanks.

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik : That's the same problem. Even when $f$ depends only on $\phi$, $\Delta f$ depends on $a$. So your statement "In principle, the biharmonic operator is obtained after applying twice the above operation" is false.